# How do I subscribe for push updates when an attendee cancels their participation in a calendar entry I own?

Tags: calendar, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm working with EWS and I've set up a push subscription via the [PushSubscriptionRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563599(v=exchg.150).aspx) to the `DistinguishedFolderId` called `calendar`. I've got a working listener that receives the SOAP requests the EWS sends.

My application allows the user to register for some training course. When a user does that, the application creates a new appointment that is owned by the application's Exchange account, and invites the user as the sole participant. That way I get one appointment per user for each course, which makes sure that the users do not know about each other until they attend the actual event.

When people change their mind and do not want to attend any more, they are supposed to log into the application and cancel their attendance. Obviously they don't do that, because it's much more convenient to just click "no" in Outlook. They think they are not going, but in the application they still use up a valuable space in the course because the application never learns about their cancellation.

In order to mitigate this, I want my app to get notified when one of those calendar events changes. I've subscribed for the `ModifiedEvent`, because I figured that sounds reasonable.

However, I only get `ModifiedEvent` notifications shortly after the application creates a new event. I also get a lot of `StatusEvent` messages, as I've set the `StatusFrequency` to 1 for testing. When I accept or unaccept an invitation to one of these events with a normal mailbox user through Outlook the application does not get a push notification.

**How can I get notified when someone cancels their participation?**

Maybe I am using the wrong type of event, or I am subscribed to the wrong thing.

I'm not including any code or SOAP messages because I think this is a language-agnostic problem. Both the client and the server are implemented in Perl and are embedded in Catalyst application, but I think that's not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct notification type is `ModifiedEvent`. They get fired when an attendee changes their state. The problem I had was that I had forgotten to send SOAP responses to the initial message the EWS sent to my application. It then decided not to send anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The Exchange mailbox itself may not be set up to automatically acknowledge responses to meeting requests. There is a mailbox level setting in Exchange that controls this behavior. If it's not set, then there is no way through EWS to force Exchange to acknowledge the response.

The setting is called **Automatically process meeting requests and cancellations**, under Resource Scheduling settings.

Comment: That sounds very valid. My application's user account does not have the OWA role(/permission) though. Is this something that an administrator can configure for me, or should I ask them to tick whatever box lets me log into the OWA to change that setting myself?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think you should get the admin to give you full editing rights to change the setting yourself. This [article](https://msonlinehelpdesk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200561507-How-do-I-change-resource-conference-room-scheduling-options-in-Office-365-) might give you some guidance.

Comment: This exact setting didn't exist in our OWA. There is one to automatically delete updates to invitations when they are marked accepted, and one for removing cancelled invitations. However, I've found the solution and will write an answer shortly. I forgot to send SOAP responses to EWS and that cancelled out the subscription.